# Deploy SQL scripts stored in a folder along with click once installer

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I am working on a windows forms application in which I am using few SQL scripts and executing them in my server using the C# application. Everything is working fine. I am able to run the scripts in my application which in turn creates tables in the database specified.

However my issue is I want to ship these SQL scripts located in that folder along the clickonce installer while deploying. The installer does not include the SQL files while installing.

Below is my code.

```
lstInfo.Items.Add(Resources.domaintable_initialization);
var file = new FileInfo(Path.GetFullPath(Application.StartupPath + "/scripts/createtbl_script.sql"));
SScriptFile = file.OpenText().ReadToEnd();
SUpdateDBname = SScriptFile.Replace("db_project", database);
var sUpdateServer = new Server(new ServerConnection(sqlConnection));
sUpdateServer.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(SUpdateDBname);
sqlConnection.Close();
lstInfo.Items.Add(Resources.domaintable_success);
```

I have added the scripts folder inside debug -> bin directory. However when I publish the package i am not able to call the scripts located in that path as that folder inside bin is not getting published and I am getting the error that the path is not valid and scripts not getting called once installed using the clickonce package.

Can anyone help me on how to achieve this? I want a path to which I will be able to add the SQL scripts and able to have the same scripts added to my deployment package once published.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include these files in the visual studio project. Just right click on the project and add an already existing element.

Select your scripts and add them to the project.

After that right click on the script files an click on properties. Now you will see a property build or something like that. There you can use the dropbox and select 'Content'.

Below that you will find another dropbox which should read something like "Dont't copy". Set the value of that dropbox to "Always copy".

That should do the trick.